# Are holomorphic maps regular maps of varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is a holomorphic map of complex algebraic varieties always a regular map?

Comment: Well, is $\exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic map? Is it regular?

Comment: But if you add the magic word _projective_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no additional assumptions, the answer is no, cf. the comment about $\mathop{\text{exp}}:\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}$. However, if the varieties involved are *proper* $\mathbf{C}$-varieties, equivalently, the associated complex analytic spaces (manifolds if the varieties are smooth) are *compact*, then every holomorphic map is regular. In the projective this is (part of) the famous GAGA theorem of Serre (Ann. Inst. Fourier 6 (1956)), which was extended to the proper case by Grothendieck (SGA 1, exp. XII).

Comment: If $X/\Bbb{C}$ is an algebraic variety and $X^{an}$ is compact, do we have $X\to Spec(\Bbb{C})$ proper?